# I fetch data from an API in postgress database using pg pool with Nodejs. I get data in 2D array each array is candle information

Tags: node.js, postgresql

This is the format of data I receive.

```
[
        [
            1627875900,
            15874.9,
            15876.9,
            15834.65,
            15847.05,
            0
        ],
        [
            1627875960,
            15847.05,
            15853,
            15838.7,
            15853,
            0
        ],
        [
            1627876020,
            15854.25,
            15861.85,
            15853.6,
            15861.05,
            0
        ],
        [
            1627876080,
            15860.35,
            15862.85,
            15856,
            15859.4,
            0
        ]
]
```

If I use loop to store it then order changes because of async. Please help me in this direction how to store or store at once with each array element as a record.

here is my snippet.

```
const newCandle = response.candles.map(async (element) => {
        await pool.query(
          `INSERT INTO nifty_50 (date, open, high, low, close) VALUES ('${element[0]}', '${element[1]}', '${element[2]}', '${element[3]}', '${element[4]}')`
        );
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for inserting in database:

1. Convert record to flatten array and use params

```js
function expand(rowCount, columnCount, startAt=1){
  var index = startAt
  return Array(rowCount).fill(0).map(v => `(${Array(columnCount).fill(0).map(v => `$${index++}`).join(", ")})`).join(", ")
}

// flatten([[1, 2], [3, 4]]) returns [1, 2, 3, 4]
function flatten(arr){
  var newArr = []
  arr.forEach(v => v.forEach(p => newArr.push(p)))
  return newArr
}
```

```js
const response = {
  candles: [
    [
      1627875900,
      15874.9,
      15876.9,
      15834.65,
      15847.05,
      0
    ],
    [
      1627875960,
      15847.05,
      15853,
      15838.7,
      15853,
      0
    ]
  ]
};

const candles = response.candles.map((v) => ([v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4]]));

await pool.query(
  `INSERT INTO nifty_50 (date, open, high, low, close) VALUES ${expand(candles.length, 5)}`,
  flatten(candles),
);
```

2. Use Postgres insert/select query (if all array data has been number format)

```js
await pool.query(
  `INSERT INTO nifty_50 (date, open, high, low, close) SELECT t.data[i][1], t.data[i][2], t.data[i][3], t.data[i][4], t.data[i][5] FROM (SELECT $1::NUMERIC[][] AS data) t CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, array_length(t.data, 1)) i`,
  [response.candles],
);
```